# Some thresholds in one column in Grafana

Tags: grafana

I need to set different thresholds in one column. It must depend on values in other column. For example, if the value in the first column is “DVG-CUBE01-VRU1”, i need to set the threshold for value in first row in “U (A), V” column. If value in third field “DVG-CUBE01-VRU3”, I need to set other threshold in third row in “U (A), V” column. Is it possible?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVenP.png)

I don't have any ideas(

Comment: What do you mean by "set different thresholds" exactly? And why is your question tagged with promql but not prometheus? Is that supposed to convey something?

Comment: I mean different thresholds is set different limit values for rows in one column. I tried to explain this in description and on screenshot

Comment: As of today it's not possible.